# Copying a file to a system directory

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is there a way to copy a file into a system directory without having root?

I'm interested about any directory, but specifically about `/system` and `/etc`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no chance to access system folders without root.